# Verify if the row is not available in mySQL table

Tags: java, mysql

I want message (the row is not available in the stock) if row is not available in the database. I try the following code but the error....!

//Code

```
try {

            Connection con = Database.mySqlCon();
            String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM stock WHERE idProduct =?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()){
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is available in Stock"
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID:" + txtS.getText() + "is not available in the Stock please update the Stock");

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

// error....

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
```

.....
.....
....
....
 Please help.....

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the value for the ? in your `SELECT` statement.

Given that it's an ID I will assume it is an int.

You need:

```
Connection con = Database.mySqlCon();
String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM stock WHERE idProduct =?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, value);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

**EDIT**

Try changing your methodology to this:

```
Connection con = Database.mySqlCon();
String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM stock WHERE idProduct =?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, value);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is available in Stock"
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID:" + txtS.getText() + "is not available in the Stock please update the Stock");
}
```

Comment: Opsss thanks @ Matt i more problem with i enter the id of row that is not available in the sql table i got the first row of the table instead of massage... ..

Comment: @MuhammadKashif I have added an edit. Try it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ Matt for help

i got a perfect Answer by using this code......

try {

```
            Connection con = Database.mySqlCon();
            String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM stock WHERE idProduct =?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, txtS.getText());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();



            int count = 0;
            while (rs.next()){

                // code update here

                count = rs.getInt(1);
              //  count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1) {
```